# goJS dropdown for link text

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have simple python flask app where I send JSON data to my HTML and with goJS I display my graph which looks like this:

[image]

I want to make custom choices dropdown for users to edit node and link text. So far, I used this code to make nodes text selectable in dropdown list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>State Chart</title>
<meta name="description" content="A finite state machine chart with editable and interactive features." />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='go.js')}}"></script>

<!-- custom text editors -->
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorSelectBox.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='TextEditorRadioButtons.js')}}"></script>


<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='DataInspector.js')}}"></script>

<link href="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='DataInspector.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script id="code">

    var nodeChoices = ['choice 1', 'choice 2', 'choice 3', 'choice 4', 'choice 5'];
    var linkChoices = ['link choice 1', 'link choice 2', 'link choice 3', 'link choice 4', 'link choice 5'];

    function init() {

        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
            // start everything in the middle of the viewport
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            // have mouse wheel events zoom in and out instead of scroll up and down
            "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,
            // support double-click in background creating a new node
            "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { text: "new node" },
            // enable undo & redo
            "textEditingTool.defaultTextEditor": window.TextEditorSelectBox,
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
            "layout": new go.ForceDirectedLayout()
        });


        // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
            var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
            if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
            var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
            if (myDiagram.isModified) {
                if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
            } 
            else {
                if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
            }
        });

        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("textEdited", function(e) {
            console.log("Text is edited");
            console.log(e);

            //CHECK IF LINK,
            //IF YES REMOVE THAT OPTION FROM LIST

        });

        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionDeleting", function(e) {
            console.log("inside SelectionDeleting");
            console.log(e);

            //CHECK IF LINK,
            //IF YES PUT THAT OPTION BACK IN OPTION LIST

        });

            // define the Node template
        myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
          $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
              {
                parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                stroke: null,
                portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                toLinkable: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                cursor: "pointer"
              }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                editable: true,  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                //textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons, // defined in textEditorRadioButtons.js
                // this specific TextBlock has its own choices:
                textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons,
                //choices: JSON.parse('{{ choices | tojson | safe}}')
                choices: nodeChoices
              },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );

        myDiagram.nodeTemplate.selectionAdornmentTemplate =
        $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
            $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, { stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2, fill: null }),
            $(go.Placeholder)
        ),
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
            { alignment: go.Spot.Top, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom },
            $("Button",
                { click: editText },  // defined below, to support editing the text of the node
                $(go.TextBlock, "t",
                { font: "bold 10pt sans-serif", desiredSize: new go.Size(15, 15), textAlign: "center" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            { // drawLink is defined below, to support interactively drawing new links
                click: drawLink,  // click on Button and then click on target node
                actionMove: drawLink  // drag from Button to the target node
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L8 0 8 12 14 12 M12 10 L14 12 12 14" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            {
                actionMove: dragNewNode,  // defined below, to support dragging from the button
                _dragData: { text: "?????", color: "lightgray" },  // node data to copy
                click: clickNewNode  // defined below, to support a click on the button
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L3 0 3 10 6 10 x F1 M6 6 L14 6 14 14 6 14z", fill: "gray" })
          )
        )
      );

    function editText(e, button) {
        //console.log(e);

      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      console.log("node");
      //console.log(node);
      e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
      //$("#nodeText").val(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
    }

    function drawLink(e, button) {
      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.linkingTool;
      tool.startObject = node.port;
      e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
      tool.doActivate();
    }

   // used by both clickNewNode and dragNewNode to create a node and a link
    // from a given node to the new node
    function createNodeAndLink(data, fromnode) {
        var diagram = fromnode.diagram;
        var model = diagram.model;
        var nodedata = model.copyNodeData(data);
        model.addNodeData(nodedata);
        var newnode = diagram.findNodeForData(nodedata);
        var linkdata = model.copyLinkData({});
        model.setFromKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(fromnode.data));
        model.setToKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(newnode.data));
        model.addLinkData(linkdata);
        diagram.select(newnode);
        return newnode;
    }

    // the Button.click event handler, called when the user clicks the "N" button
    function clickNewNode(e, button) {
        var data = button._dragData;
        if (!data) return;
        e.diagram.startTransaction("Create Node and Link");
        var fromnode = button.part.adornedPart;
        var newnode = createNodeAndLink(button._dragData, fromnode);
        newnode.location = new go.Point(fromnode.location.x + 200, fromnode.location.y);
        e.diagram.commitTransaction("Create Node and Link");
    }

    // the Button.actionMove event handler, called when the user drags within the "N" button
    function dragNewNode(e, button) {
        var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
        if (tool.isBeyondDragSize()) {
            var data = button._dragData;
            if (!data) return;
            e.diagram.startTransaction("button drag");  // see doDeactivate, below
            var newnode = createNodeAndLink(data, button.part.adornedPart);
            newnode.location = e.diagram.lastInput.documentPoint;
            // don't commitTransaction here, but in tool.doDeactivate, after drag operation finished
            // set tool.currentPart to a selected movable Part and then activate the DraggingTool
            tool.currentPart = newnode;
            e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
            tool.doActivate();
        }
    }

    // using dragNewNode also requires modifying the standard DraggingTool so that it
    // only calls commitTransaction when dragNewNode started a "button drag" transaction;
    // do this by overriding DraggingTool.doDeactivate:
    var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
    tool.doDeactivate = function() {
        // commit "button drag" transaction, if it is ongoing; see dragNewNode, above
        if (tool.diagram.undoManager.nestedTransactionNames.elt(0) === "button drag") {
            tool.diagram.commitTransaction();
        }
        go.DraggingTool.prototype.doDeactivate.call(tool);  // call the base method
    };

    // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
            curve: go.Link.Bezier, 
            adjusting: go.Link.Stretch,
            reshapable: true, 
            relinkableFrom: true, 
            relinkableTo: true,
            toShortLength: 3
        },
        new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("curviness"),
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
            { strokeWidth: 1.5 }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
            { toArrow: "standard", stroke: null }),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape,  // the label background, which becomes transparent around the edges
            {
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Radial", { 0: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 0.3: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 1: "rgba(240, 240, 240, 0)" }),
                stroke: null
            }),
            $(go.TextBlock,  // the label text
            {
                textAlign: "center",
                font: "12pt helvetica, arial, sans-serif",
                margin: 4,
                editable: true,  // enable in-place editing
                textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons,
                //choices: JSON.parse('{{ choices | tojson | safe}}')
                choices: linkChoices
            },
            // editing the text automatically updates the model data
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        )
    );


    var inspector = new Inspector('myInspectorDiv', myDiagram,
    {
        // uncomment this line to only inspect the named properties below instead of all properties on each object:
        // includesOwnProperties: false,
        properties: {
            "text": { },
            // an example of specifying the type
            "password": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'password' },
            // key would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it read-only also:
            "key": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent },
            // color would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it a color also:
            "color": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'color' },
            // Comments and LinkComments are not in any node or link data (yet), so we add them here:
            "Comments": { show: Inspector.showIfNode  },
            "flag": { show: Inspector.showIfNode, type: 'checkbox' },
            "LinkComments": { show: Inspector.showIfLink },
            "isGroup": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent }
        }
    });

    // read in the JSON data from flask
    loadGraphData();

    }

    function loadGraphData() {
        var graphDataString = JSON.parse('{{ diagramData | tojson | safe}}');
        console.log("graphDataString");
        console.log(graphDataString);

        myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(graphDataString);
    }

    function saveGraphData(form, event) {
        console.log("inside saveGraphData");
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
        form.submit();
    }

    function zoomToFit(){
        console.log("inside zoomToFit");
        myDiagram.zoomToRect(myDiagram.documentBounds);
    }

    function zoomIn(){
        console.log("inside zoomIn");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.increaseZoom();
    }
    function zoomOut(){
        console.log("inside zoomOut");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.decreaseZoom();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

    <div id=formWrapper style="padding: 30px;">

        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/updateResultFile" name="updateResultFileForm" 
        id="updateResultFileForm" 
        onsubmit="saveGraphData(this, event);">

            <div id="graphWrapper" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100%; height: 800px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
                <div style="display: none;"><input id="mySavedModel" name="mySavedModel"></div>

                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> Save <i class="fa fa-save"> </i> </button>

            </div>

        </form>

        <div id="myInspectorDiv">
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomToFit()"> Zoom to fit  <i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomIn()"> Zoom in  <i class="fa fa-search-plus"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomOut()"> Zoom out  <i class="fa fa-search-minus"> </i> </button>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And It looks like this:

[image]

It's all fine with node text, but I have problem with link text. I want when user selects one option that he can not use that option anymore on other link texts. Also I want to make when that link is deleted that that option is available again.

As you can see in code, I added 2 event listeners on my diagram (textEdited and SelectionDeleting) and they work fine when user is editing text or deleting something, but I don't know how to extract information about event object and its text.

I need to make sure it is link so I can remove or add that event object text in my choices list. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's assume that the list of choices for the link labels is held in the **Model.modelData** object.  I'll name the property "choices", but of course you can use whatever name you like.

`myDiagram.model.set(myDiagram.model.modelData, "choices", ["one", "two", "three"]);`

Your Link template might look something like:

    `myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,
        $(go.Shape),
        $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "OpenTriangle" }),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          {
            background: "white",
            editable: true,
            textEditor: window.TextEditorSelectBox, // defined in extensions/textEditorSelectBox.js
            textEdited: function(tb, oldstr, newstr) {
              var choices = tb.diagram.model.modelData.choices;
              var idx = choices.indexOf(newstr);
              if (idx >= 0 && oldstr !== newstr) {
                console.log("removing choice " + idx + ": " + newstr);
                var newchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(choices);
                newchoices.splice(idx, 1);
                tb.diagram.model.set(tb.diagram.model.modelData, "choices", newchoices);
                tb.editable = false;  // don't allow choice again
              }
            }
          },
          new go.Binding("text"),
          new go.Binding("choices").ofModel())
      );`

Note how the **TextBlock.textEditor** is defined to be a `TextEditorSelectBox` and the **TextBlock.textEdited** event handler is defined to set the `modelData.choices` property to be a new Array without the chosen string.

It also sets **TextBlock.editable** back to false so that the user cannot re-choose for that Link.  That's one way to avoid problems with repeated edits; but you could implement your own policies.  In retrospect I think the more likely policy would be to add the old value to and remove the new value from the `modelData.choices` Array.

Also, you'll want to implement a Model Changed listener that notices when Links have been removed from the model, so that you can add its choice back to the `myDiagram.model.modelData.choices` Array.  In your **Diagram** initialization:

    `$(go.Diagram, . . .,
      {
            "ModelChanged": function(e) {
              if (e.change === go.ChangedEvent.Remove && e.modelChange === "linkDataArray") {
                var linkdata = e.oldValue;
                var oldstr = linkdata.text;
                if (!oldstr) return;
                var choices = e.model.modelData.choices;
                var idx = choices.indexOf(oldstr);
                if (idx < 0) {
                  console.log("adding choice: " + oldstr);
                  var newchoices = Array.prototype.slice.call(choices);
                  newchoices.push(oldstr);
                  e.model.set(e.model.modelData, "choices", newchoices);
                }
              }
            }
      })`

Comment: Can you explain why diagram shows default options inside dropdown when I change key in modelData from "choices" to something else. I checked 5x and I changed key in all places where is needed, still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know -- the property name really doesn't matter.  My guess is that you missed a use of "choices", or you have a typo in one of the new property names.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I tried with multiple property names and it only works with property name set as "choices". Also it doesn't allow me to use 2 or more properties for dropdown choices. In documentation there is nothing mentioned about that limit. Can you take a look at my updated question, I think my logic is ok, but it still doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891610/gojs-dropdown-remove-items